# alert when toggle is switched

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to show an alert whenever the toggle is on and off but finding it difficult.
I followed this tutorial but mine is not working as it should

http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/iwuvC

JS

```
.controller('shops',['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope,$http,$timeout){
  $http.get('http://localhost/site/templates/shop.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.shops=data ;   
    $scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      alert('Push Notification Change: '+ $scope.pushNotification.checked);
    }, 0);
  };
  $scope.pushNotification = { checked: true };
  });
}])
```

HTML

```
<ion-view  align-title="center">
  <ion-content overflow-scroll="false" has-bouncing="true" class=padding>
  <ion-list>
    <div ng-controller="shops" ng-repeat="item in shops">
      <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap"> 
        <img src="img/index/fashion.png" alt="photo" width="32" height="32" />
        <h2>{{item.shop_name}} </h2>
        <p>{{item.biz_location}}</p>
        <div align="right">
          <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
          <input type="checkbox"ng-model="pushNotification.checked"
                    ng-change="pushNotificationChange()">
            <div class="track"><div class="handle"></div></div>
          </label>
        </div> 
      </ion-item>
    </div>   
  </ion-list> 
  </ion-content overflow-scroll="false" has-bouncing="true">        
</ion-view>
```

any help on how to make this work?

Comment: why all code is wrapped inside `$http.get` success, it should be outside $http callback

Comment: @PankajParkar, thanks for the tip. 
supposing there are two or more toggle switches and by default one is turn on automatically and when another is turned on how do i make the first one turn off

Answer (score 1):

Your code is all inside http, it should be outside:

```
.controller('shops',['$scope','$http','$timeout',function($scope,$http,$timeout){
  $http.get('http://localhost/site/templates/shop.php').success(function(data){
     $scope.shops=data;   
  });

  $scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      alert('Push Notification Change: '+   $scope.pushNotification.checked);
    }, 0);
  };
  $scope.pushNotification = { checked: true };    
}])
```

Comment: thanks it worked. supposing there are two or more toggle switches and by default one is turn on automatically and when another is turned on how do i make the first one turn off

Comment: inside the function where you have the alert, you would do something like this, $scope.pushNotificationSecond = { checked: false };

 pushNotificationSecond being the second switch =)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ion-view  align-title="center">
  <ion-content overflow-scroll="false" has-bouncing="true" class=padding>
  <ion-list>
   <div ng-controller="shops">
    <div ng-repeat="item in shops">
      <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap"> 
        <img src="img/index/fashion.png" alt="photo" width="32" height="32" />
        <h2>{{item.shop_name}} </h2>
        <p>{{item.biz_location}}</p>
        <div align="right">
          <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
          <input type="checkbox"ng-model="pushNotification.checked"
                    ng-change="pushNotificationChange()">
            <div class="track"><div class="handle"></div></div>
          </label>
        </div> 
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    </div> 
  </ion-list> 
  </ion-content overflow-scroll="false" has-bouncing="true">        
</ion-view>
```